# Basic4Android - GPS in service apps

Tags: android, service, gps, basic4android

how to use GPS in service . i have activity work fine with GPS but in service not work.

how handle this event in service :

```
Sub GPS_LocationChanged (Location1 As Location)
    Dim Lat, Lon As String
    Lat = Location1.Latitude
    Lon = Location1.Longitude   

    lblLat.Text = Lat
    lblLon.Text = lon

    Dim req As HttpRequest
    req.InitializeGet("http://1.aspx?lat=" & Lat & "&Lon=" & Lon)
    hc.Execute(req, 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Dit you add the gps service to your AndroidManifest.xml? You have to add the permissions to you application.

Example of activating and using GPS: https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/using-the-gps

What kind of service are you trying to write? Cus the URL you are using is kinda strange.

Comment: i use basic4android . my activity work fine with GPS. but in service can't use gps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between using GPS in a service or in an activity. Make sure to start the service with StartService keyword.